# Private Ethereum PoA error: "out of memory"

Tags: go-ethereum, memory, poa, geth-clique

I'm working with multi node setup on Ethereum private chain PoA. We have all three validator nodes.

```
blockchain    
├── genesis.json    
├── node1    
│   ├── geth    
│   ├── keystore    
│   ├── password.txt    
│   └── static-nodes.json    
├── node2    
│   ├── geth    
│   ├── keystore
│   ├── password.txt    
│   └── static-nodes.json    
└── node3    
    ├── geth    
    ├── keystore
    ├── password.txt    
    └── static-nodes.json
```

Server Configuration:

CPU: 4 core 
Storage: 100 GB SSD 
RAM: 16 GB 
SWP: 976 MB  
Geth: 1.8.16

During testing I found that while making concurrent request on server, all the memory gets exhausted, and the first validator node goes down.

Geth logs shows error as

[image]

What I have tried?

I have tried to add cache parameter like --cache=10, however it doesn't make any difference.

Is there any way to handle it?